# Apply() cannot be applied to this list?

Tags: r

I have created an example below, where I am trying to make a list of each row of a matrix, then use apply().

```
mat<-matrix(rexp(9, rate=.1), ncol=3)

my_list2 <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) { 
  my_list2[[i]] <- mat[i,]
}

#DO NOT CHANGE THIS:
apply(my_list2[[i]],2,sum)
```

However the apply() function does not work, giving a dimension error. I *understand* that apply() is not the best function to use here but it is present in a function that I need so I *cannot* change that line.

Does anyone have any idea how I can change my "my_list2" to work better? Thank you!

Edit:

Here is an example that works (non reproducible)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w91QV.png)

Note both the example above and this example have type "list"

Comment: FYI, your screenshot does not correspond to your code: in the screenshot, the first element of a `list` (I'm inferring) named `ex` is a matrix with 2 rows; in your code, each element is a vector.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to show a different way of sharing data: if you do `dput(ex[1:2])` and paste that output into your question, we use your data *unambiguously*. Welcome to SO! It is normal and expected that questions will be fully reproducible, and while your first question here is a good start (sample data and some code), it does not appear that the sample data here is representative of your real code. FYI, your current sample-data/code can be improved by using `my_list2[[i]] <- mat[i,,drop=FALSE]` in your `for` loop, and a good chance to learn about that option :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses "how to properly get a list of matrices", not how to resolve the use of `apply`.

By default in R, when you subset a matrix to a single column or a single row, it reduces the dimensionality. For instance,

```r
mtx <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
mtx
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6
mtx[1,]
# [1] 1 3 5
mtx[,3]
# [1] 5 6
```

If you want a single row or column but to otherwise retain dimensionality, add the `drop=FALSE` argument to the `[`-subsetting:

```r
mtx[1,,drop=FALSE]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
mtx[,3,drop=FALSE]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    5
# [2,]    6
```

In this way, your code to produce sample data can be adjusted to be:

```r
set.seed(42) # important for reproducibility in questions on SO
mat<-matrix(rexp(9, rate=.1), ncol=3)

my_list2 <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) { 
  my_list2[[i]] <- mat[i,,drop=FALSE]
}

my_list2
# [[1]]
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 1.983368 0.381919 3.139846
# [[2]]
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 6.608953 4.731766 4.101296
# [[3]]
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 2.83491 14.63627 11.91598
```

And then you can use [akrun's most recent code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71529970/3358272) to resolve how to get the row-wise sums within each list element, i.e., one of

```r
lapply(my_list2, apply, 2, sum)
lapply(my_list2, function(z) apply(z, 2, sum))
lapply(my_list2, \(z) apply(z, 2, sum)) # R-4.1 or later
```

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot it works because the object part of the list ex[[1]] is an array. And in your example the elements of your list are vectors. You could try the following:

```
mat<-matrix(rexp(9, rate=.1), ncol=3)

my_list2 <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) { 
  my_list2[[i]] <- as.matrix(mat[i,])
}

#DO NOT CHANGE THIS:
apply(my_list2[[1]],2,sum)
apply(my_list2[[2]],2,sum)
apply(my_list2[[3]],2,sum)
```

You should note that apply cannot be applied to all three elements of the array in one line. And to do it in one, that line should be changed.